# "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tesseract'" even though everything is installed

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm working on reading text from images, and have installed all the pre-requisites for ocrmypdf.

1. `pip install pytesseract`
2. `sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr`
3. `pip install ocrmypdf`

But even after all of that is installed, I still get

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tesseract'.

Funny thing is, the function `ocrmypdf.ocr()` works just fine when I use the python shell to invoke it instead of a `.py`file. That would suggest that there is no issues with my installation or path where `tesseract-ocr` is installed.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: check the `environment` in which you have installed the packages and in which `environment` your script is running? seems `environment-mismatch`

Comment: What OS are you using?
Also share your code which gives this error.

Comment: @Kaneki21 Both instances (`shell` and `.py`) are running on the same `environment`. In fact, there is only 1 `environment` and python is not installed outside the `environment`.

Comment: @Ahmad Anis, OS is ubuntu. I don't know if error code is something different, but the console only shows `[Error 2]`, which I assume is the error code.

Comment: I meant `python virtual environment`. Wherever you run the script, can you run `pip list`, check if `tesseract` is present or not

Comment: Are you importing `tesseract` or `pytesseract` because you have installed `pytesseract`

Comment: @Kaneki21 I'm talking about `virtual environment` as well, but I'm using `conda env`

Comment: @AhmadAnis, I have installed both, I'm importing neither. I'm only importing `ocrmypdf`,which is also what I did in the `shell` where it worked.

Comment: can you check the `pip list` too, sometimes dependency packages are also there, can you check the docs of `ocrmypdf` so that no dependency package is missed

Comment: Are you using VS Code? or PyCharm

Comment: @Kaneki21, Just checked and all dependencies are installed. Moreover, if dependencies had issues, I think it wouldn't have worked in the shell.

Comment: @AhmadAnis, I am using `VSCode` for coding. I'm executing the code (both `shell` and `.py` ) using the ubuntu terminal (ie. not inside any editor)